# Cambiar de estado Randomico al presionar un boton Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Deseo cambiar de estado randomico de un sonido cuando aplasto un boton, pero sigue en el mismo estado, existe algun comando que me permita usar los otros valores randomicos cuando presiono el boton.

```
Integer [] sonidos =  {
            R.raw.yellow,
            R.raw.red,
            R.raw.blue,
    };

    Integer [] images_numbers = {0,1,2};
    Integer [] sonidos_numbers = {0,1,2};

    Random r = new Random();
    int start = 0;
    int end = 3;
    int playRandom = r.nextInt(end-start);
    int turns = 0;
```

En el primer apartado yo genero el array de valores que en este caso estan en la carpeta raw, en la segunda parte del codigo uso el valor randomico para determinar el color, sin embargo para el proximo valor no se como calcular

```
 if (sonidos_numbers[playRandom]==0)
                {
                    playSound_amarillo();

                    color_amarillo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            color_amarillo.setImageResource(images[images_numbers[0]]);
                            color_amarillo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }else if (sonidos_numbers[playRandom]==1)
                    {
                    playSound_rojo();

                    color_rojo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            color_rojo.setImageResource(images[images_numbers[1]]);
                            color_rojo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                });
                }
```

Comment: Hola, te sugiero agregar, como calculas los valores "randomicos"? y ese valor "randomico" en donde lo usas en tu código.

Comment: Hola como estas, gracias por tu consejo, acabo de editar la pregunta, el problema que tengo es que quiero tomar valores randomicos con un boton pero una vez que presione el boton el valor randomico tambien debe cambiar

Comment: Ok quieres obtener valores random de sonidos, images_numbers y sonidos_numbers

Comment: Si exactamente, pero al primer intento funciona bien, al segundo intento no se como tomar solo los otros dos valores  del random de sonido que restan

Comment: Ok , revisa mi respuesta, con el método será suficiente para usarlo en donde desees, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Deseas obtener un elemento random en base a el array de elementos, para esto puedes realizar un método el cual reciba un array pero entregue un elemento random contenido en el array:

```
private static int getRandom(Integer[] array){
     Random r = new Random();
     int start = 0;
     int end = 3;
     //obtiene numero random entre 0 y 2
     int playRandom = r.nextInt(end-start) + start;
     //Obtiene elemento en array en base a número random
     return array[playRandom];
}
```

Ahora el anterior método puedes usarlo de esta forma:

```
//Obtiene valor aleatorio e array sonidos_numbers.
int valorRandom = getRandom(sonidos_numbers);

if (valorRandom  == 0) {
    playSound_amarillo();

    color_amarillo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            color_amarillo.setImageResource(images[images_numbers[0]]);
            color_amarillo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
} else if (valorRandom == 1) {
    playSound_rojo();

    color_rojo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            color_rojo.setImageResource(images[images_numbers[1]]);
            color_rojo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

---

El mismo método puedes usarlo para obtener valor aleatorio para los array `sonidos` e  `images_numbers`  , ejemplos:

```
int valorSonidos = getRandom(sonidos);
int valorImages = getRandom(images_numbers);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, funciona como quiero pero al momento de generar nuevos valores estos se repiten hay manera de que si ya salio un valor no vuelva a salir, espero me puedas ayudar con esto mas

Comment: Recuerda al preguntar siempre definir todos los detalles de tu pregunta ok. Dime pero cuando se hayan salido los 3 valores la cuarta vez que valor mostrarías, el último?

Comment: Entiendo que lo que menciono en el comentario no se encuentra en la pregunta principal, me gustria generar una sola vez cada valor aleatorio, al finalizar los tres valores el boton que ejecuta los valores desaparece